# Testing the cast

Tags: java

I have a problem with casting, want to check the casting and one place before the method finishes, because of interfaces and extended methods I don't have many options to do it elsewere. The method after the one I can modify will try to cast a object.

```
public class A<ReturnType> extends B<C, D, E> {

...

private isObjectValid(Object o) {

    ... checks for nulls, api execptions etc... when it's happy i want to test casting

    try {

      final ReturnType test = (ReturnType) o;
      return true;

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {

      callback.onFailure(((ApiException) o).getMessage());
      return false;
    }
```

I have a dilemma now. Because the test is unused variable, will that be executed anyway or removed in some optimisation process when compiling? This will be compiled with regular Java (no openJDK) and android devEnviroment as well. Can I be sure this code always will be there and executed?

I can't use **o instanceof ReturnType** when the class is generic <> diamond.

Is there any not dodgy way to make sure the casting is tested first and which will work no matter what compiler you use (even in the future)?

The ReturnTypes are known and it's about dozen of them, I can't just have if else statement if it's one of them, because even it could be from correct types, it still could be the wrong one for this instance.

Comment: Due to type erasure, that is not possible.  You need a `Class<ReturnType>`.

Comment: The main idea of generics is to insure declarative type compatibility (at compile time).

Comment: For the instance of I get that the ReturnType is sort of Object and I will be just calling Object is instance of Object. But then how i you would ensure with generics that the desired type is returned when method arguments are Objects and the other methods cast it and sometimes fail. I want to introduce checking (on runtime) before the cast will be run and the then change response. The other place where it's really casted into something else can't be touched.